# How do i create a keyboard shortcut to open a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, customization

How do i create a keyboard shortcut to open a chrome app or web page?
How to do it from the command line?

Comment: In `~/.local/share/applications`, your app is represented by a .desktop file. Please post the content of the file's Exec= -line

Comment: things such as:
chrome-aohghmighkkkiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop
chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhiekkkgkjlhalf-Default.desktop

Comment: Put the content of those desktop files in the question.

Comment: ^exactly, open the file e.g. with gedit or run `cat file.desktop`

Answer (score 5):

Open URL from command line:
`google-chrome http://www.example.com`

Open URL as application from command line:
`google-chrome --app=http://www.example.com`

Create keyboard shortcut for opening URL:
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom > +
- Name: Foo
- Command: `google-chrome http://www.example.com`
- Press Apply
- Select the new row, then press and hold down the desired keys

Create keyboard shortcut for opening URL as application:
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom > +
- Name: Bar
- Command: `google-chrome --app=http://www.example.com`
- Press Apply
- Select the new row, then press and hold down the desired keys

Answer (score 3):

Find your chrome app shortcuts files at: `~/.local/share/applications`

You will find there a list of `*.desktop` files. In the inside they will look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Google Drive
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U --profile-directory=Default --app-id=apdfllckaasghufndbhieahigkjlhiii
Icon=chrome-apdfllckaasghufndbhieahigkjlhiii-Default
NoDisplay=true
StartupWMClass=crx_apdfllckaasghufndbhieahigkjlhiii
```

Copy that exec command to your shortcut command.

`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=apdfllckaasghufndbhieahigkjlhiii`

credit to @Jacob Vlijm