# Shortcut to open a browser with a switch, such as -ssb or -kiosk

Tags: firefox, icons, desktop-environments, shortcuts, url

I'd like to ask how to create a clickable shortcut in a folder (or desktop) to open a browser with a `switch`, pointing to a specific webpage.

Below example refers to open a webpage in a Single Site Browser (`-ssb`). But this could also be in kiosk-mode, such as using the `-kiosk` switch

In Windows, you right-click anywhere, on the desktop or in a folder to create a shortcut and type the following:
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -ssb [https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask%22)

***Q: How does the corresponding step by step procedure looks like in Ubuntu (>18.04) ?***

---

*I have tried below*

In other posts it is referred to a shortcut to firefox, but this necessary needs to live in the application folder, such as this post: [How to create desktop shortcut for Firefox 79 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272355/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-for-firefox-79-on-ubuntu-20-04)

And I am not permitted to drag and drop

> "Drag and Drop is not supported / an invalid drag type was used"

when dragging the little keylock left of the address bar (https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in Firefox to a folder within Documents folder
[How to create a desktop shortcut to a website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269788/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-to-a-website)

Below is promising but refer to a short-cut key, but very easy way of doing it [How do i create a keyboard shortcut to open a chrome app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895627/how-do-i-create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-chrome-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple line script for that purpose.

1. Create a file (name it whatever you want to and where ever you want)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

    # You can add "-kiosk" flag after firefox to open the window in kiosk mode
    firefox "https://www.askubuntu.com"  #(add any URL you want)
   ```

2. Give execute permissions with `chmod +x filename`
3. Then ***right click*** on file then --> ***properties*** --> ***permissions*** --> and tick on **Allow executing file as a program**
4. Then go to **Open With** tab and select ***Run Software*** as the default application to open the file with.

Now, you can click twice on the file to directly open link you desire in firefox

Comment: did exactly as above, (copy and paste your code into a new file and did 2, 3, 4), just get a spinning wheel in Ubuntu 20.10. Can you check on your side, and potentially corrent your answer, please.

Comment: Are you using ".sh" as an extension? If yes, remove it. If it still doesn't work remove the 'exec' command from the code.

Comment: strange, doesn't work, its a completely new install of Ubuntu 20.10, so no tampering/settings with bash etc.  I have -rwxrwxr-x  rights on the file which I call "test", created with touch and edited with nano.

Comment: Have you tried removing 'exec' command from the code and then running it(by double-clicking on it)? Or copy and paste code once again, I have made a couple of changes. And it still works on my machine.

Comment: from firefox --help  ...   I see an option ...   firefox --new-Window <url>

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for your dock or application launcher (a .desktop file)

#### Option 1: Replacing the existing Firefox launcher

This method gives you the option to launch kiosk mode the same way you can launch private browsing - by right-clicking the icon on the dock or the application launcher and choosing a separate option there.

1. Copy the current desktop file (probably from `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`) to `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop`.
2. Open it with a text editor.
3. Add this section to the end of the file:

```
[Desktop Action new-kiosk-window]
Name=Open a Kiosk Mode Window
Exec=firefox -kiosk
```

4. Find this line in the file:

```
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;
```

and replace it with

```
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;new-kiosk-window;
```

5. Save & exit. Log out of OS, log in.

#### Option 2: Adding an alternative Firefox kiosk launcher

Same as above, but:

- Rename the file to `/.local/share/applications/firefox_kiosk.desktop` instead of having the same name.
- Change the `Name=` and `Description=` to something you want and the `Exec=` line to `firefox -kiosk` instead of other changes to the `firefox_kiosk.desktop` file. If you want, you can also change the `Icon=`.